# Not able to access json file using python

Tags: python, json

```
'''
[
    {
      "File": "https://nnts.imgix.net/uploadedfiles/32749cff-2ab6-42be-bdfc-c4145cf6f8a7/PredictionImages/675799006.jpeg?expires=1631997475&or=0&s=130f04ce02987c65f927c783d3d51e17",
      "original_filename": "15667 (4101).jpg",
      "page": 0,
      "col 1": "Company\nName:",
      "col 2": "Aces Electronic Co. Ltd. (3605) Taiwan"
    },
    {
      "File": "https://nnts.imgix.net/uploadedfiles/32749cff-2ab6-42be-bdfc-c4145cf6f8a7/PredictionImages/675799006.jpeg?expires=1631997475&or=0&s=130f04ce02987c65f927c783d3d51e17",
      "original_filename": "15667 (4101).jpg",
      "page": 0,
      "col 1": "Company Profile:",
      "col 2": "ACES Electronics Co., LAB. is principally\nengaged in the development, design,\nmanufacture and distribution of\nelectronic connectors and related\nacces"
    },
    {
      "File": "https://nnts.imgix.net/uploadedfiles/32749cff-2ab6-42be-bdfc-c4145cf6f8a7/PredictionImages/675799006.jpeg?expires=1631997475&or=0&s=130f04ce02987c65f927c783d3d51e17",
      "original_filename": "15667 (4101).jpg",
      "page": 0,
      "col 1": "Chairman:",
      "col 2": "Gu"
    },
    {
      "File": "https://nnts.imgix.net/uploadedfiles/32749cff-2ab6-42be-bdfc-c4145cf6f8a7/PredictionImages/675799006.jpeg?expires=1631997475&or=0&s=130f04ce02987c65f927c783d3d51e17",
      "original_filename": "15667 (4101).jpg",
      "page": 0,
      "col 1": "Mailing Address:",
      "col 2": "Alive Mitake Building, Shibuya Ku,\nTokyo, 150 - 0002, Japan"
    },
    {
      "File": "https://nnts.imgix.net/uploadedfiles/32749cff-2ab6-42be-bdfc-c4145cf6f8a7/PredictionImages/675799006.jpeg?expires=1631997475&or=0&s=130f04ce02987c65f927c783d3d51e17",
      "original_filename": "15667 (4101).jpg",
      "page": 0,
      "col 1": "Website:",
      "col 2": "www.sanei.net"
    },
    {
      "File": "https://nnts.imgix.net/uploadedfiles/32749cff-2ab6-42be-bdfc-c4145cf6f8a7/PredictionImages/675799006.jpeg?expires=1631997475&or=0&s=130f04ce02987c65f927c783d3d51e17",
      "original_filename": "15667 (4101).jpg",
      "page": 0,
      "col 1": "Nation:",
      "col 2": "TAIWAN"
    },
    {
      "File": "https://nnts.imgix.net/uploadedfiles/32749cff-2ab6-42be-bdfc-c4145cf6f8a7/PredictionImages/675799006.jpeg?expires=1631997475&or=0&s=130f04ce02987c65f927c783d3d51e17",
      "original_filename": "15667 (4101).jpg",
      "page": 0,
      "col 1": "Classification:",
      "col 2": "Electronics"
    },
    {
      "File": "https://nnts.imgix.net/uploadedfiles/32749cff-2ab6-42be-bdfc-c4145cf6f8a7/PredictionImages/675799006.jpeg?expires=1631997475&or=0&s=130f04ce02987c65f927c783d3d51e17",
      "original_filename": "15667 (4101).jpg",
      "page": 0,
      "col 1": "Sub-Classification:",
      "col 2": "Miscellaneous Electronics"
    },
    {
      "File": "https://nnts.imgix.net/uploadedfiles/32749cff-2ab6-42be-bdfc-c4145cf6f8a7/PredictionImages/675799006.jpeg?expires=1631997475&or=0&s=130f04ce02987c65f927c783d3d51e17",
      "original_filename": "15667 (4101).jpg",
      "page": 0,
      "col 1": "Recorder:",
      "col 2": "TAI"
    },
    {
      "File": "https://nnts.imgix.net/uploadedfiles/32749cff-2ab6-42be-bdfc-c4145cf6f8a7/PredictionImages/675799006.jpeg?expires=1631997475&or=0&s=130f04ce02987c65f927c783d3d51e17",
      "original_filename": "15667 (4101).jpg",
      "page": 0,
      "col 1": "PEG:",
      "col 2": "36PRC5"
    },
    {
      "File": "https://nnts.imgix.net/uploadedfiles/32749cff-2ab6-42be-bdfc-c4145cf6f8a7/PredictionImages/675799006.jpeg?expires=1631997475&or=0&s=130f04ce02987c65f927c783d3d51e17",
      "original_filename": "15667 (4101).jpg",
      "page": 0,
      "col 1": "P. E. Ratio:",
      "col 2": "4,538,152,000 (Year Ending Jan2010)."
    },
    {
      "File": "https://nnts.imgix.net/uploadedfiles/32749cff-2ab6-42be-bdfc-c4145cf6f8a7/PredictionImages/675799006.jpeg?expires=1631997475&or=0&s=130f04ce02987c65f927c783d3d51e17",
      "original_filename": "15667 (4101).jpg",
      "page": 0,
      "col 1": "Sedol:",
      "col 2": ""
    },
    {
      "File": "https://nnts.imgix.net/uploadedfiles/32749cff-2ab6-42be-bdfc-c4145cf6f8a7/PredictionImages/675799006.jpeg?expires=1631997475&or=0&s=130f04ce02987c65f927c783d3d51e17",
      "original_filename": "15667 (4101).jpg",
      "page": 0,
      "col 1": "Currency Traded In:",
      "col 2": "TD"
    },
    {
      "File": "https://nnts.imgix.net/uploadedfiles/32749cff-2ab6-42be-bdfc-c4145cf6f8a7/PredictionImages/675799006.jpeg?expires=1631997475&or=0&s=130f04ce02987c65f927c783d3d51e17",
      "original_filename": "15667 (4101).jpg",
      "page": 0,
      "col 1": "Listing Date:",
      "col 2": "23-07-2001"
    },
    {
      "File": "https://nnts.imgix.net/uploadedfiles/32749cff-2ab6-42be-bdfc-c4145cf6f8a7/PredictionImages/675799006.jpeg?expires=1631997475&or=0&s=130f04ce02987c65f927c783d3d51e17",
      "original_filename": "15667 (4101).jpg",
      "page": 0,
      "col 1": "No. Of Employees:",
      "col 2": "6,164/EUA"
    },
    {
      "File": "https://nnts.imgix.net/uploadedfiles/32749cff-2ab6-42be-bdfc-c4145cf6f8a7/PredictionImages/675799006.jpeg?expires=1631997475&or=0&s=130f04ce02987c65f927c783d3d51e17",
      "original_filename": "15667 (4101).jpg",
      "page": 0,
      "col 1": "Market Capital:",
      "col 2": "MC6,922,496,000"
    },
    {
      "File": "https://nnts.imgix.net/uploadedfiles/32749cff-2ab6-42be-bdfc-c4145cf6f8a7/PredictionImages/675799006.jpeg?expires=1631997475&or=0&s=130f04ce02987c65f927c783d3d51e17",
      "original_filename": "15667 (4101).jpg",
      "page": 0,
      "col 1": "Outstanding Shares:",
      "col 2": "os123,616,000"
    },
    {
      "File": "https://nnts.imgix.net/uploadedfiles/32749cff-2ab6-42be-bdfc-c4145cf6f8a7/PredictionImages/675799006.jpeg?expires=1631997475&or=0&s=130f04ce02987c65f927c783d3d51e17",
      "original_filename": "15667 (4101).jpg",
      "page": 0,
      "col 1": "Issued Shares:",
      "col 2": "IS23,101,644"
    }
  ]

'''
```

Not able to access json file using python.  Suppose I want to get the information in column 2 in every dictonary how do I get it using. And how to get this if there is multiple dictonary in same .json file but there will be change in original_filename.
And Suppose I want to get col 2 details using col 1 as a key how do I do that.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Yashwanth M , do you want to edit the json file.

Comment: I have tried to access the data but i am not getting what i want

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Let me know if this helps. Id comment if I had more reputation but its at least a starting point hopefully.

```
json_example = [
    {
      "File": "https://nnts.imgix.net/uploadedfiles/32749cff-2ab6-42be-bdfc-c4145cf6f8a7/PredictionImages/675799006.jpeg?expires=1631997475&or=0&s=130f04ce02987c65f927c783d3d51e17",
      "original_filename": "15667 (4101).jpg",
      "page": 0,
      "col 1": "Company\nName:",
      "col 2": "Aces Electronic Co. Ltd. (3605) Taiwan"
    },
    {
      "File": "https://nnts.imgix.net/uploadedfiles/32749cff-2ab6-42be-bdfc-c4145cf6f8a7/PredictionImages/675799006.jpeg?expires=1631997475&or=0&s=130f04ce02987c65f927c783d3d51e17",
      "original_filename": "15667 (4101).jpg",
      "page": 0,
      "col 1": "Company Profile:",
      "col 2": "ACES Electronics Co., LAB. is principally\nengaged in the development, design,\nmanufacture and distribution of\nelectronic connectors and related\nacces"
    },
    {
      "File": "https://nnts.imgix.net/uploadedfiles/32749cff-2ab6-42be-bdfc-c4145cf6f8a7/PredictionImages/675799006.jpeg?expires=1631997475&or=0&s=130f04ce02987c65f927c783d3d51e17",
      "original_filename": "15667 (4101).jpg",
      "page": 0,
      "col 1": "Chairman:",
      "col 2": "Gu"
    },
    {
      "File": "https://nnts.imgix.net/uploadedfiles/32749cff-2ab6-42be-bdfc-c4145cf6f8a7/PredictionImages/675799006.jpeg?expires=1631997475&or=0&s=130f04ce02987c65f927c783d3d51e17",
      "original_filename": "15667 (4101).jpg",
      "page": 0,
      "col 1": "Mailing Address:",
      "col 2": "Alive Mitake Building, Shibuya Ku,\nTokyo, 150 - 0002, Japan"
    },
    {
      "File": "https://nnts.imgix.net/uploadedfiles/32749cff-2ab6-42be-bdfc-c4145cf6f8a7/PredictionImages/675799006.jpeg?expires=1631997475&or=0&s=130f04ce02987c65f927c783d3d51e17",
      "original_filename": "15667 (4101).jpg",
      "page": 0,
      "col 1": "Website:",
      "col 2": "www.sanei.net"
    },
    {
      "File": "https://nnts.imgix.net/uploadedfiles/32749cff-2ab6-42be-bdfc-c4145cf6f8a7/PredictionImages/675799006.jpeg?expires=1631997475&or=0&s=130f04ce02987c65f927c783d3d51e17",
      "original_filename": "15667 (4101).jpg",
      "page": 0,
      "col 1": "Nation:",
      "col 2": "TAIWAN"
    },
    {
      "File": "https://nnts.imgix.net/uploadedfiles/32749cff-2ab6-42be-bdfc-c4145cf6f8a7/PredictionImages/675799006.jpeg?expires=1631997475&or=0&s=130f04ce02987c65f927c783d3d51e17",
      "original_filename": "15667 (4101).jpg",
      "page": 0,
      "col 1": "Classification:",
      "col 2": "Electronics"
    },
    {
      "File": "https://nnts.imgix.net/uploadedfiles/32749cff-2ab6-42be-bdfc-c4145cf6f8a7/PredictionImages/675799006.jpeg?expires=1631997475&or=0&s=130f04ce02987c65f927c783d3d51e17",
      "original_filename": "15667 (4101).jpg",
      "page": 0,
      "col 1": "Sub-Classification:",
      "col 2": "Miscellaneous Electronics"
    },
    {
      "File": "https://nnts.imgix.net/uploadedfiles/32749cff-2ab6-42be-bdfc-c4145cf6f8a7/PredictionImages/675799006.jpeg?expires=1631997475&or=0&s=130f04ce02987c65f927c783d3d51e17",
      "original_filename": "15667 (4101).jpg",
      "page": 0,
      "col 1": "Recorder:",
      "col 2": "TAI"
    },
    {
      "File": "https://nnts.imgix.net/uploadedfiles/32749cff-2ab6-42be-bdfc-c4145cf6f8a7/PredictionImages/675799006.jpeg?expires=1631997475&or=0&s=130f04ce02987c65f927c783d3d51e17",
      "original_filename": "15667 (4101).jpg",
      "page": 0,
      "col 1": "PEG:",
      "col 2": "36PRC5"
    },
    {
      "File": "https://nnts.imgix.net/uploadedfiles/32749cff-2ab6-42be-bdfc-c4145cf6f8a7/PredictionImages/675799006.jpeg?expires=1631997475&or=0&s=130f04ce02987c65f927c783d3d51e17",
      "original_filename": "15667 (4101).jpg",
      "page": 0,
      "col 1": "P. E. Ratio:",
      "col 2": "4,538,152,000 (Year Ending Jan2010)."
    },
    {
      "File": "https://nnts.imgix.net/uploadedfiles/32749cff-2ab6-42be-bdfc-c4145cf6f8a7/PredictionImages/675799006.jpeg?expires=1631997475&or=0&s=130f04ce02987c65f927c783d3d51e17",
      "original_filename": "15667 (4101).jpg",
      "page": 0,
      "col 1": "Sedol:",
      "col 2": ""
    },
    {
      "File": "https://nnts.imgix.net/uploadedfiles/32749cff-2ab6-42be-bdfc-c4145cf6f8a7/PredictionImages/675799006.jpeg?expires=1631997475&or=0&s=130f04ce02987c65f927c783d3d51e17",
      "original_filename": "15667 (4101).jpg",
      "page": 0,
      "col 1": "Currency Traded In:",
      "col 2": "TD"
    },
    {
      "File": "https://nnts.imgix.net/uploadedfiles/32749cff-2ab6-42be-bdfc-c4145cf6f8a7/PredictionImages/675799006.jpeg?expires=1631997475&or=0&s=130f04ce02987c65f927c783d3d51e17",
      "original_filename": "15667 (4101).jpg",
      "page": 0,
      "col 1": "Listing Date:",
      "col 2": "23-07-2001"
    },
    {
      "File": "https://nnts.imgix.net/uploadedfiles/32749cff-2ab6-42be-bdfc-c4145cf6f8a7/PredictionImages/675799006.jpeg?expires=1631997475&or=0&s=130f04ce02987c65f927c783d3d51e17",
      "original_filename": "15667 (4101).jpg",
      "page": 0,
      "col 1": "No. Of Employees:",
      "col 2": "6,164/EUA"
    },
    {
      "File": "https://nnts.imgix.net/uploadedfiles/32749cff-2ab6-42be-bdfc-c4145cf6f8a7/PredictionImages/675799006.jpeg?expires=1631997475&or=0&s=130f04ce02987c65f927c783d3d51e17",
      "original_filename": "15667 (4101).jpg",
      "page": 0,
      "col 1": "Market Capital:",
      "col 2": "MC6,922,496,000"
    },
    {
      "File": "https://nnts.imgix.net/uploadedfiles/32749cff-2ab6-42be-bdfc-c4145cf6f8a7/PredictionImages/675799006.jpeg?expires=1631997475&or=0&s=130f04ce02987c65f927c783d3d51e17",
      "original_filename": "15667 (4101).jpg",
      "page": 0,
      "col 1": "Outstanding Shares:",
      "col 2": "os123,616,000"
    },
    {
      "File": "https://nnts.imgix.net/uploadedfiles/32749cff-2ab6-42be-bdfc-c4145cf6f8a7/PredictionImages/675799006.jpeg?expires=1631997475&or=0&s=130f04ce02987c65f927c783d3d51e17",
      "original_filename": "15667 (4101).jpg",
      "page": 0,
      "col 1": "Issued Shares:",
      "col 2": "IS23,101,644"
    }
  ]

for json_object in json_example:
    print(json_object['col 2'])
    if json_object['col 1'] == 'Issued Shares:':
        print('Filtered results: ' + json_object['col 2'])
```